# How to get multiple inputs Python

Tags: python, input

I'm writing a program in Python where I would like to do the following:
I ask for a certain input by writing

```
x = int(input())
```

Now, given the number 'N' I assign to this input, I would to then get N lines asking for new input. For example, if I give as input the number 3, I would like the program to ask for 3 new inputs and assign them to certain letters:

```
x = int(input())
3
```

Then

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 2):

Assigning them to certain variables with an unknown amount of inputs is not something you want. What you can do is make a list with the inputs:

```
x = int(input()) # the amount of numbers
input_list = []
for i in range(x):
    input_list.append(input())
print input_list
```

Now you can index the input_list to get the n-th input:

```
print input_list[0]
```

This will return the first input as the indexing in Python starts from 0

Comment: And how can I use these amounts of input? If I would like to use the first or last element in input_list for further programming?

Comment: First element: input_list[0] and last element: input_list[-1], look at some list tutorials how to iterate over them and interact with them

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to follow previous answer, but if you care about giving meaningful names to the user's inputs you can do the following:

```
import sys
current_module = sys.modules[__name__] # you will have an access to module instance
print("Define number of further inputs:")
no = input()
for x in range(int(no)):
    print("Input value: ")
    _var = input()
    setattr(this_module, 'var_%s' % _var, _var)
```

After that, you can access those variables through the next code:

```
globals()[name_of_the_variable]
```

where name_of_the_variable is 'var_' plus user's input value, for example

```
Define number of further inputs: 5

var_5 = globals()['var_5']
```

Hope that would help you.